# Using a pandas dataframe as an argument when writing function in Python

Tags: python, function, arguments

The following code to generate a quick plot of some data works fine when I run it in the cell within my notebook:

```
def xyz_plot(df=df, sensor='acc', position='t', activity='walking_treadmill_flat', 
        person=np.random.randint(1,9)):
        sensors = [f'{position}_{i}{sensor}' for i in ['x','y','z']]
        subset = df.query(f"person=='{person}' & activity=='{activity}'")
        for j in sensors:
            sns.lineplot(subset.seconds[100:200], subset[f'{j}'][100:200], label=f'{j}', legend='full').set(xlabel='', ylabel='Seconds',                                                      title=f'Person:{person}')
```

However, when I save it in `my_functions.py` file which I have imported as follows it no longer works and cannot find my data frame. How can I fix this?

```
from my_functions import xyz_plot
```

Comment: What is the error it shows? And second, in the example, the function is not used only defined.Do you pass the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call your function, pass the argument to it, rather than setting it as a default argument!

If you must have default arguments, make sure they're [not mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

function declaration

```py
def myfunction(arg, arg2=None):
    work_with_arg(arg)
```

function call

```py
from mylibrary import myfunction

...
myfunction(dataframe)  # arg refers to the dataframe in the function
```

This structure should also be used to prevent problems with your `person` argument (see note about mutable default args), as the *random value will be calculated only once* on import / function declaration (which may be desired, but probably isn't..)

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def broken(x=np.random.randint(1,9)):
...     print(x)
...
>>> broken()
7
>>> broken()
7
>>> broken()
7
>>> broken()
7
```

more proper

```py
>>> def happy(x=None):
...     if x is None:
...         x=np.random.randint(1,9)
...     print(x)
...
>>> happy()
4
>>> happy()
7
```

Comment: That fixed it thank you! Thanks for the extra clarification, much appreciated.